# commons-compress "will not fit in octal"

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a java program that needs to tar/gz a large bit of data (14 gigs) and I am using commons-compress. This will be a re-occuring job every week and is automated.

When I attempt to compress something of this size I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 13313903445=143144405525 will not fit in octal number buffer of length 11
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarUtils.formatUnsignedOctalString(TarUtils.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarUtils.formatLongOctalBytes(TarUtils.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry.writeEntryHeader(TarArchiveEntry.java:749)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:209)
    at com.broadridge.adc.core.commons.io.ADCFileUtils.addFilesToCompression(ADCFileUtils.java:144)
    at com.broadridge.adc.core.commons.io.ADCFileUtils.addFilesToCompression(ADCFileUtils.java:154)
    at com.broadridge.adc.core.commons.io.ADCFileUtils.compressFiles(ADCFileUtils.java:125)
    at com.broadridge.adc.core.commons.io.ADCFileUtils.compressFile(ADCFileUtils.java:106)
```

My code works fine for smaller amounts of information (around 600 megs).  I've looked at the source code but it's not clean to my why the error is occurring.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It might be that the tar version used by commons-compress is the old style that has a 8 gig limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exceeding some limit defined by [TarConstants.SIZELEN](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.3/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarConstants.java#TarConstants.0SIZELEN) which is 12.

What Javadoc tells us about this:

> The length of the size field in a header buffer. Includes the trailing
>   space or NUL.

It is used by [TarArchiveEntry.writeEntryHeader(byte[] outbuf)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.3/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveEntry.java#TarArchiveEntry.writeEntryHeader%28byte%5B%5D%29) which is in your stacktrace. Later in the stack this limit is subtracted by 1 resulting in a limit of 11 which is part of your exception message.

Later in the call stack [TarUtils.formatUnsignedOctalString(final long value, byte[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.2/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarUtils.java#TarUtils.formatUnsignedOctalString%28long,byte%5B%5D,int,int%29) is called where the limit of 11 is exceeded.

So you seem to exceed some maximum header field size.

Comment: The actually programmatic solution is to set the BigNumberMode in the TarArchiveOutputStream (in commons-compress 1.4 or >) code: TarArchiveOutputStream taos = new TarArchiveOutputStream(
   new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos)));
  taos.setBigNumberMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.BIGNUMBER_STAR); 
  taos.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_GNU);

Comment: When you found a solution where you do not run into that kind of problem then provide as an answer to your own question. I do not leave in a huff when you accept your own answer. My answer only points at the problem, your answer provides a solution which is much more valuable.